# How can I find directories to zip with specific path structure

Tags: bash, unix, find, zip

I am in bash.

I have the following directories.

```
/mydir/moredirs/archivethis1
/mydir/moredirs/archivethis2
/mydir/moredirs/subdirA
/mydir/moredirs/subdirB
```

I am **able** to cd to `/mydir/moredirs`
and then
`zip ~/archivethis1.zip archivethis1/*.*`

I want to use find as follows:

```
cd /mydir/moredirs
find * -type d -name "archive*" -exec zip ~/{}.zip {}/*.* \;
```

I receive following error:

> zip warning: name not matched: zip error: Nothing to do!

Can I use find to find all directories named archive and then zip them with the same path structure as running the zip command as illustrated for a single directory. Note, this is why I am using `find * vs find .` and why I cd into parent directory to make that the CWD.

I prefer using `/*.* vs -r` flag as this does not include empty dir in zip structure.

Comment: `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "archive*" -exec zip -r ~/{}.zip {} \;`

Comment: If you only want to archive direct subdirectories of `/mydir/moredirs` you don't need `find`. `for d in archive*/ ; do zip -r ~/"${d%/}".zip "$d" ; done`

Answer (score 1):

I have to correct my suggestion

> find: warning: you have specified the global option -maxdepth after
> the argument -type, but global options are not positional, i.e.,
> -maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it.  Please specify global options before other arguments.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d  -name "archive*" -exec zip -r ~/"{}".zip "{}" \;
```

Comment: I forgot the maxdepth will be important.